# CAML Query throwing error

Tags: caml-query

Pretty new to CAML queries, but trying to query a list based on Status = Completed and a date range.

It is throwing the following error "Unexpected Error: One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields. Microsoft.SharePoint"

Status and Created are both system columns, so 99.9% sure I have the Field Names correct I have tested the query without the Date Range and it runs as expected, so I think my problem is somewhere in between `<geq>` and `</leq>`  From what I have read, Created expects time to follow date. Query is below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <Where>   
    <And>                               
    <And>    
    <Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" />Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value></Eq> 
    </And>          
    <Geq>         
    <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE"    
    Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T00:00:01Z</Value>
    </Geq>
    <Leq>              
    <FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" 
    Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T23:59:59Z</Value>
    </Leq>
    </And> 
    </Where>
```

Answer (score 4):

You've got a missing `<` before your first `Value>` and a misplaced `<And>` between the `<Eq>` and `<Geq>` that should be after the `</Geq>`.

```
<Where>
    <And>                               
        <And>    
            <Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" /><Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value></Eq>      
            <Geq>         
                <FieldRef Name="Created" />
                <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T00:00:01Z</Value>
            </Geq>
        </And>
        <Leq>              
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T23:59:59Z</Value>
        </Leq>
    </And> 
</Where>
```

Also, this may be better:

```
<Where>
    <And>                               
        <Eq><FieldRef Name="Status" /><Value Type="Choice">Completed</Value></Eq>      
        <Eq>         
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="FALSE" Type="DateTime">2013-07-02T00:00:00Z</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

Comment: It is also possible to use <Value Type="Text">Completed</Value> in query, no need to use choice if there is no multichoice column

Comment: Stuart, Thanks so much. No more errors, but this CAML query is part of a web part that performs a copy between libraries based on Completed Status and the date range.
I am testing this in a Dev environment and I have had to use another date field for the range as "Created" is defaulted to the date I uploaded all the test items.

Comment: Anyway, I have no issue specifying the other column, (it is named Alerts Received) but when I try and just specify items from 7/2/13 0:00:00 to 7/2/13 23:59:59 or your second example, everything that copies over to the destination library is for (Alert Received) 7/3/13, not 7/2/2013. Thoughts?

Comment: I had a similar problem with timezones a while back, but the detail of the cause escapes me at the moment.